# How to get userName by email Address using powershell Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

How to get userName by email Address using powershell in Sharepoint 2013. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods are available, both equally valid

## 1

```
$users = Get-SPUser -Web http://siteCollectionWhereUserExist
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    if($user.Email -eq "name.lastname@company.com")
    {
        Write-Host $user.UserLogin
    }
}
```

## 2

You can also filter using `Where-Object`

```
Get-SPUser -web https://intranet.mysite.com | Where-Object {$_.Email -eq "email@domain.com"} | select UserLogin
```

Comment: The Get_SPuser is not working in office 365 Sharepoint online management shell

Comment: True, but you asked for server (see your tags). If you want answer for SPOnline, edit the tags in this question or ask a new one.